# help with global_costmap parameters

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I created my own global planner as a plugin ros, for now, it generates a simple straight line to the goal point and will not take into account any obstacles. The local planner should try to walk that straight line. However, my global planner must generate this line in the odometry frame, it will not be necessary a map or the AMCL node. What would be the correct way to initialize the global_costmap.yaml parameters?

```
global_costmap:
   global_frame: /odom
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   ??
```

*case description:

I know a destination point that is X meters away from the center of the robot(base_footprint). I want to trace a trajectory (without considering any obstacles) and I want ROS to drive the robot through the created trajectory. I had thought of creating a global planner, but maybe there is a better way. Any suggestion?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357115/help-with-global_costmap-parameters/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

just start with the default settings for navigation

```
global_frame: /map   
robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
.
.
```

I was having problems with the "control loop frequency" in the move_base node, so I increased the transform_tolerance in AMCL and solved it

---

Originally posted by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) with karma: 125 on 2020-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0